# PHP edit unique row in table

Tags: php, unique

I currently have a PHP form that uses AJAX to connect to MySQL and display records matching a user's selection ([AJAX: Display MySQL data with value from multiple select boxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593317/ajax-display-mysql-data-with-value-from-multiple-select-boxes))

As well as displaying the data, I also place an 'Edit' button next to each result which displays a form where the data can be edited. My problem is editing unique records since currently I only use the selected values for 'name' and 'age' to find the record. If two (or more) records share the same name and age, I am only able to edit the first result.

Comment: Add the id as a hidden variable, then use it to find the right one: {id: 10, name: jim, age:29}

Comment: I have tried setting the ID of the record as the id of the 'Edit' button: id="{$row['ID']}" but I don't know how to retrieve or use this value

Comment: You can use $_REQUEST['id'] to retrieve the value of id at server side.

Comment: @pinaki Can you give an example of how to use this? I have tried print $_REQUEST['id']; in my edit form to check the correct value is passed but nothing appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your file for editing is edit.php. Then, in the file where you generate the edit links, try changing your edit button link as follows:

> ```
> '<a href="edit.php?id="'.$row['ID'].'">edit</a>'
> ```

Then you will be able to access ID variable as

> ```
> echo $_REQUEST['ID'];
> ```

Note that the ID is case sensitive. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without a separate edit.php? My 'edt' function is in index.php and the links are generated in getPages.php. I tried $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] but it didnt run the function nor append the id to the url

Comment: Also, my index.php file runs the 'edit' function on $_POST['edit'] which breaks if I use a hyperlink instead

Answer (score 0):

when displaying records from ajax, also send the primary field(id in most cases) along with name and age

and when u are displaying these data along with edit incorporate that primary field with edit

Comment: I have set the id of each edit button to the ID of the record diplayed in the same row. I can't get access to it though

Comment: ok if u r sure u have retrieve id correctly then u can do 2 things


1) if working in forms: Have a hidden field in the form. and set the id in its value field just like u did with edit
like:

<input type="hidden" name="myId" value="whatever the id is">
then on submitting u can retrieve the id by $_REQUEST['myId']


2. if without form then u can use javascript on edit button 
Like:


<input type="button" name="editID" value="Edit" onclick="location.href='editthis.php?myId=whatever the id is'">


and can retrieve like $_GET['myId'];